# Powershell calling function in a workflow

Tags: powershell, workflow, powershell-2.0

I am trying to call a log function inside a work flow. Log function has write-host which is not supported by workflows. How can I call any function which has indirect workflow restrictions inside a workflow?

Edit
Example: **color parameter will not show when it is inside function call from** workflow.

```
function log($string, $color)
{
  $logfile = "C:\users\MyFolder\Logs_$(get-date -format `"yyyyMMdd_hhmmss`").txt"
   if ($Color -eq $null) {$color = "white"}
   write-host $string -foregroundcolor $color
   $string | out-file -Filepath $logfile -append
}

workflow myworkflow{
log "I am from log function" yellow
}
```

Comment: This does work for me. What error you get?

Comment: It won't show color if it is inside a function.

Comment: You should clarify that in your question...